# Trying to find the point when two functions differ from each other a 5% with Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, intersection

As I've written in the title, I'm trying to find the exact distance (dimensionless distance in this case) when two functions start to differ from each other a 5% of the Y-axis. The two functions intersect at the value of 1 in the X-axis and I need to find the described distance before the intersection, not after (i.e., it must be less than 1). I've written a Matlab code for you to see the shape of the functions and the following calculations which I'm trying to make them work but they don't, I don't know why. "Explicit solution could not be found".

I don't know if I explained it clearly. Please let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.

I hope you can throw some light in this issue.

Thank you so much in advanced.

```
r=0:0.001:1.2;
ro=0.335;
rt=r./ro;
De=0.3534;
k=2.8552;
B=(2*k/De)^0.5;
Fm=2.*De.*B.*ro.*[1-exp(B.*ro.*(1-rt))].*exp(B.*ro.*(1-rt));
A=5;
b=2.2347;
C=167.4692;
Ftt=(C.*(exp(-b.*rt).*((b.^6.*rt.^5)./120 + (b.^5.*rt.^4)./24 + (b.^4.*rt.^3)./6 +         (b.^3.*rt.^2)./2 + b.^2.*rt + b) - b.*exp(-b.*rt).*((b.^6.*rt.^6)./720 + (b.^5.*rt.^5)./120 + (b.^4.*rt.^4)./24 + (b.^3.*rt.^3)./6 + (b.^2.*rt.^2)./2 + b.*rt + 1)))./rt.^6 - (6.*C.*(exp(-b.*rt).*((b.^6.*rt.^6)./720 + (b.^5.*rt.^5)./120 + (b.^4.*rt.^4)./24 + (b.^3.*rt.^3)./6 + (b.^2.*rt.^2)./2 + b.*rt + 1) - 1))./rt.^7 - A.*b.*exp(-b.*rt);
plot(rt,-Fm,'red')
axis([0 2 -1 3])
xlabel('Dimensionless distance')
ylabel('Force, -dU/dr')
hold on
plot(rt,-Ftt,'green')
clear rt
syms rt
%assume(0<rt<1)
r1=solve((Fm-Ftt)/Ftt==0.05,rt)
r2=solve((Ftt-Fm)/Fm==0.05,rt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the crux of floating point data.  The reason why is because for the values of `r` that you are providing, the exact solution of `0.05` may be **in between** two of the values in your `r` array and so you won't be able to get an **exact** solution.  Also, FWIW, your equation may **never** generate a solution of 0.05, which is why you're getting that error too.  Either way, doing that explicit solve on floating point data is never recommended, unless you know very well how your data are shaped and what values you expect for the output of the function you're applying the data to.

As such, it's always recommended that you find the **nearest** value that satisfies your condition.  As such, you should do something like this:

```
[~,ind] = min(abs((Fm-Ftt)./Ftt - 0.05)); 
r1 = r(ind);
```

The first line will find the nearest location in your `r` array that satisfies the 5% criterion.  The next line of code will then give you the value that is in your `r` array that satisfies this.  You can do the same with `r2` by:

```
[~,ind2] = min(abs((Ftt-Fm)./Fm - 0.05)); 
r2 = r(ind2);
```

What the above code is basically doing is that it is trying to find at what point in your array would the difference between your data and 5% be 0.  In other words, which point in your `r` array would be close enough to make the above relation equal to 0, or essentially when it is as close to 5% as possible.

If you want to improve this, you can always change the step size of `r`...  perhaps make it `0.00001` or something.  However, the smaller the step size, the larger your array and you'll eventually run out of memory!

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your time. It worked, but now I have certain doubts. The code you've given me finds the point in my "r" array (I've changed the step size to 0.000001) that satisfies the aforementioned condition. I'm searching the value of "rt" that satisfies that condition so I would have to divide the result by "ro", if I'm not mistaken. The thing is that I get a value of "r" of 0.0026 and divided by ro I get 0.0078. What does that value mean? I'm supposed to get a value of rt very close to 1 (0.9xxx), isn't it? Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JMOsorio - I'm not familiar with the math or theory behind your equations so I can't help you with understanding the context.  I looked at your code objectively and it was looking for a solution that satisfied a condition, and I worked with that.  The context behind what the values actually mean will be up to you.  However, when you get 0.0026, that means that it is the value in your `r` array that is the **closest** to 5%.  How close that is is another story, so if you want it closer, you'll have to play around with the step size.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that, looking at the graph (https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8gqbwohv5kzvo1/matlab.jpg), the result I get makes no sense with the imposed condition since the curves must differ a 5% at a certain point very close to the intersection, not at almost the zero... A solution could be telling Matlab to find the r value between 0.9 and 1 for example? Thanks!!

Comment: @JMOsorio - My gut feeling is that the equation itself that you're trying to solve isn't right.  Double check it again.  I just went with your code and assumed it work on faith.

Comment: @JMOsorio - I noticed that you're plotting the negative of the curve.  Could this be a factor in solving the equation?

Comment: I don't think so. Should it be? What equation must I use to find the 5% differ then if that one is not right? I cannot think of anyone.

Comment: @JMOsorio - I'll get back to you.  I may have written the code wrong.

Comment: Thank you mate. You can PM me or email me for not to flood this :)

Comment: @JMOsorio - Hey!  Did you manage to get it work?  I'm sorry I haven't looked at it recently.  What happened?

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern! I've been thinking in how to make it work but in vain. I think the equation (Fm-Ftt)/Ftt < 0.05 it's correct and I don't really know why Matlab throw me that result... :/ everything seems correct to me, although I don't have a large knowledge about programming.